# Make image and video upload optional

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, controller

I have a small app in codeigniter. There is a form that has 3 text fields, name,email,location. This is enough to submit. However there are two optional fields to all the user to submit either an image or video or both. I have it working until there is an error with the file uploaded. It will still submit the text data, when i want it to halt the whole submission until the error is fixed.

Here is the code from my controller. Any help would be great. Thanks!

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Form extends MY_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
}

function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('nominee', 'Nominee', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('location', 'Location', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('form');
        }
        else
        {
             // Load the library - no config specified here
                $this->load->library('upload');

                // Check if there was a file uploaded - there are other ways to
                // check this such as checking the 'error' for the file - if error
                // is 0, you are good to code
                if (!empty($_FILES['imageupload']['name']))
                {
                    // Specify configuration for File 1
                    $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/images';
                    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
                    $config['max_size'] = '100';
                    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
                    $config['max_height']  = '768';       

                    // Initialize config for File 1
                    $this->upload->initialize($config);

                    // Upload file 1
                    if ($this->upload->do_upload('imageupload'))
                    {
                        $data = $this->upload->data();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo $this->upload->display_errors();
                    }

                }

                // Do we have a second file?
                if (!empty($_FILES['videoupload']['name']))
                {
                    // Config for File 2 - can be completely different to file 1's config
                    // or if you want to stick with config for file 1, do nothing!
                    $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/videos/';
                    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
                    $config['max_size'] = '100';
                    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
                    $config['max_height']  = '768';

                    // Initialize the new config
                    $this->upload->initialize($config);

                    // Upload the second file
                    if ($this->upload->do_upload('videoupload'))
                    {
                        $data = $this->upload->data();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo $this->upload->display_errors();
                    }

                }

            $this->load->view('thankyou');
            //Run code to add into the database
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place all the upload data logic into a [custom validation callback](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks).

Then if the validation fails (including the uploads), the page will return to the form, with the data pre-filled in - and your user can fix the file upload.

Then your controller logic is simplied as well;

```
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nominee', 'Nominee', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('location', 'Location', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('imageupload', 'Image Upload', 'callback__image_upload');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('videoupload', 'Video Upload', 'callback__video_upload');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('form');
    }
    else
    {
        //Run code to add into the database
        $this->load->view('thankyou');
    }
```

and

```
function _video_upload()
{
   //put upload logic here and check if its valid
}

function _image_upload()
{
   //put upload logic here and check if its valid
}
```

Comment: Great! So just to be clear. the script for uploading the image goes in the _video_upload() functon?

Comment: yes - and you 'check' if the upload is successful - and if so return true. if not, set the validation error message and return false

Comment: ok, it works almost fine. The only problem i'm having is when i select a file for both inputs, it appears to always say the second file is too large. Is it adding them together?

Comment: I've sorted that. Was me being silly. One last question. How can i get the value of the filename that has been uploaded back to the top so I can insert it into a field in the table?